# How to make the ISBLANK function work

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

How do I insert a `ISBLANK` function in this formula?

```
=(IF(D21-T21<=S25, "TIMES-UP", (D21-T21)))
```

If cell D is blank then cell E is blank if not, then the formula above will be executed. Also, I want this function to be present on all cells on E column.

This function is not working:

```
=(IF(ISBLANK(D:D)=TRUE;"Blank cell"; (D21-T21<=S25, "TIMES-UP", (D21-T21))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`=IF(ISBLANK(D21),"Blank cell",IF(D21-T21<=S25, "TIMES-UP", (D21-T21)))`

`ISBLANK()` returns TRUE or FALSE - [Doc ref](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290) - so there's no need to test for its value.

**Side note:**

Some locales use a comma (,) as a separator, others use a semicolon (;). Your first example uses a comma; the second uses a semicolon. The answer above uses a comma.